# JasperReports: pdf to printer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I haven't found a good example of how to print a PDF file using JasperReports. Is it possible to print a PDF without creating a report? All I need the printing functionality from JasperReports since Java API for Printing PDF does not work.

My code that down:

...

```
@Path("report")
    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    @Produces({"application/pdf"})
    public Response createRaportList(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                                     @Auth  Credentials credentials, @Context UriInfo allUri) throws IOException, DRException {
        LOGGER.info("requestIssue başarı ile oluşturuldu");
        final Credentials cri=credentials;
        final OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        final List<String> lstFile=allUri.getQueryParameters().get("orderBy");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                for (String fileOid:lstFile){
                    createReportForFileOid(stream,cri,Long.parseLong(fileOid));
                }
            }
        }).run();
        return createReportForFileOid(stream,credentials,Long.parseLong(lstFile.get(0)));
    }
```

createReportForFileOid methods return Response and that is processing create jasper and pdf

Comment: Don't post question about how to use some toolkit or how to configure things.

Comment: Any toolkit :( oh may good:(

Comment: Jasperrreport is not a tool?  Have you posted any code at all? what do you want exactly?  I think from your question you are asking for a tutorial on how to print reports with Jasperreport.  Even more, you want it without writing a report template.  Is this programming at all?  Please, look at the rules to post here.

Comment: i want click button when send to printer and print

I inserting code to my questions

Comment: Well, everybody wants something...

Comment: :) I think so  my project manager want to me :(

Comment: `Is it possible to print a PDF without creating a report?` - What do you mean?

Comment: What is a reason to use JasperReports if you don't want to `create a report`?

Comment: I create one raport and pdf but not visible client and I dont know how to create many report  

how to Directly send a printer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to many report ,how to do  this case which your information case